# ELM based on LARS algorithm: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed

Tags: python, lars

I want to combine the extreme learning machine (ELM) algorithm with the LARS algorithm. I adapted the code below for this. Unfortunately I will not be able to share the dataset for data privacy reasons. All other part of the code is below. Any help would be very important to my project. Thank you.

```
# Normalized DataSet

X_n = (X - X.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)) / X.std(axis=0, keepdims=True)
y_n = (y - y.mean()) / y.std()

# Dividing the dataset test data using train_test_split.

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X_n, y_n, test_size=0.33, random_state=42) 

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-train_X))

input_size = train_X.shape[1]   

M_hidden_size = 1000

input_weights = np.random.normal(size=[input_size, M_hidden_size])

biases = np.random.normal(size=[M_hidden_size])

def hidden_nodes(X):
    G = np.dot(train_X, input_weights)
    G = G + biases
    H = sigmoid(G)
    return H 

H = hidden_nodes(X)
print("Array Dimension = ",len(H.shape))        # Array Dimension =  2

def lars(train_X, train_y):
    n, p = train_X.shape
    mu = np.zeros_like(train_y)
    beta = np.zeros(p)

    for _ in range(p):
        c = np.dot(train_X.T, (train_y - mu)) 
        c_abs = np.abs(c)
        c_max = c_abs.max() 

        active = np.isclose(c_abs, c_max)           # Array Dimension =  2
        signs = np.where(c[active] > 0,1,-1)      # Array Dimension =  1
                
        H_active = signs * H[:, active]               # print("Array Dimension = ",len(H_active.shape))
        
        G = np.dot(H_active.T, H_active)
        Ginv = np.linalg.inv(G)

        A = Ginv.sum() ** (-0.5)

        w = A * Ginv.sum(axis = 1)
        u = np.dot(H_active, w)

        gamma = c_max / A

        if not np.all(active):
            a = np.dot(train_X.T, u)
            complement = np.invert(active)
            cc = c[complement]
            ac = a[complement]
            candidates = np.concatenate([(c_max - cc) / (A - ac),
                                         (c_max + cc) / (A + ac)])
            gamma = candidates[candidates >= 0].min()
        mu += gamma * u
        beta[active] += gamma * signs
    return mu, beta

beta = lars(train_X, train_y).fit
print ('Beta:\n', beta)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\user\ELM\A.py", line 88, in 
beta = lars(train_X, train_y).fit

File "C:\Users\user\ELM\A.py", line 64, in lars
H_active = signs * H[:, active]                    # print("Array Dimension = ",len(H_active.shape))

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed